# One mouse press for several QGraphicsItem's in QT

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, mouseover, qgraphicsitem

I have a matrix of QGraphicsItem's in a QGraphicsScene and when I click an element it changes it's color. This is implemented with `mousePressEvent()`. I want to be able to click and hold and then move the cursor over other QGraphicsItem's and change their color too, hence trigger their `mousePressEvent()`.

The problem is that due to mouse grabbing the first element I click "keeps" all the events and `hoverEnterEvent()` is not triggered. I tried adding `ungrabMouse()` to `mousePressEvent()` but that didn't help.

I guess one solution would be to make the QGraphicsitem's drag-able and use QT drag and drop functions for that. In fact I have this:

```
void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    changeColor();
}
```

and when I drag some text from the application over the elements it works like I want it but not when I "drag" a QGrahphicsItem.

So is the only solution to make a QGraphicsItem dragable to be able to trigger events while hovering over them with a clicked mouse button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I added all my QGraphicsRectItem's to a QGraphicsItemGroup and implemented the events for this group. In Group::MouseMoveEvent() I check the position of the cursor and apply the event to its children. It looks like this:

```
void Group::mouseMoveEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event )
{
    if (boundingRect().adjusted(0,0,-1,-1).contains(event->pos()))
    {
        if (CellCoordinate(event->pos()) != lastChangedCell_) {
            lastChangedCell_ = CellCoordinate(event->pos());
            modifyCell(CellCoordinate(event->pos()));
        }
    }
}
```

If you have the same problem and need more info feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `mouseMoveEvent()`.

Edit: The `mouseMoveEvent()` of the parent `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work: "If you do receive this event, you can be certain that this item also received a mouse press event, and that this item is the current mouse grabber." (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html#mouseMoveEvent)

Comment: Well, it won't work in the mouseMoveEvent for QGraphicsItem. I think the solution is to implement this functionality at the QGraphicsView level, and that class's mouseMoveEvent might be helpful.

Comment: Hmm, ok, that's strange behaviour, that is not really consistent with the rest of Qt. In this case, yes, it's probably best to deal with user interaction at a higher level (i.e. QGraphicsView).